# use iphone application without submitting to apple store

Tags: ios, ios4, jailbreak

Here I am going to ask a non usual question.

I have created one application in iphone. But I do use some things/ codes that are not allowed by apple and hence it has been rejected. I can't say the things that I used.

It's a free application, but I want to distribute the same to many people using my website.

My question is Is it possible to create such kind of application and distribute without submitting the application to apple store??

using our Distribution profile OR using our provision profile for some personal use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't. Because for using ADHOC distribution, you will need to generate CUSTOM BUILD with provisioning profiles for each device it will run on. Hence, it won't scale since you won't be able to generate a new build/release everytime a new user wants to download your app.

You could distribute it through CYDIA, but only jailbroken iPhones will be able to run your app.

Sorry to bring you the bad news, but the answer is **no**.

Comment: thanks for your reply,  Can you give me any link to any further specification documentation so that I can show up to my seniors?

Comment: @iPhone Fun: you mean Apple's documentation where it says you can't distribute applications through a website?

Comment: not the apple documents , as it's too big one , it you do have any link of apple then it's fine else any other site which can say about this things.

Comment: @iPhone Fun: how about this: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

Comment: @iPhone fun: no prob fellow. Good lock with your project.

Answer (score 1):

AdHoc would not be an option for you as you're limitted to 100 devices and you need to know the UDID of every device the app should be installed on.

All other things require a jailbroken phone on the user side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I do have all the devices udid as the application is for our internal use ,so and all shall have been jailbroken... then is it possible for me ???

Comment: If you have all the UDID's you can use the AdHoc mechanism. To install AdHoch builds from a website, check out the Hockey Framework https://github.com/TheRealKerni/Hockey Edit: You don't need a jailbroken phone to use AdHoch, to make that clear.

Comment: Means i can install my application in any device whether jailbreaked or not right?

Comment: It can be installed on all devices included in the AdHoch profile. See here for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html

Comment: Fine thanks for this help, now let me do some r&d on this things that you have provided